# Print the results of the loop in recent time order

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, sorting

How can I sort the results of the two loops in order of time? They are two different loops, but I would like to order them together by mixing the first loops and the second loops in order to sort everything in time. Basically this code scrapes the time and title of some news and prints them in a textbox. They are two different loops.

I wrote this code, but it doesn't work

```
from datetime import datetime
allnews = news1, news2
allnews.sort()
```

I have no errors, but I get this output for example:

```
14.24 TEXAS RANGER #this is loop n.1
14.01 TEXAS RANGER #this is loop n.1
14.20 DETROIT #this is loop n.2
14.13 DETROIT #this is loop n.2

I want to get:
14.24 TEXAS RANGER 
14.20 DETROIT
14.13 DETROIT
14.01 TEXAS RANGER
```

Here is the part of my code useful for solving the question. I do not glue the entire code, but I only glue the piece thanks to which I print

```
#textbox
textbox = tk.Listbox(window, width=80, height=20, font=('helvetic', 12), selectbackground="#960000", selectforeground="white", bg="white")
textbox.place(x=1, y=1)

def titoli():

   #code of scraping....

    #TEXAS RANGER
    site_texasrangers = requests.get('....')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(site_texasrangers.content, 'html.parser')
    news = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "tcc-list-news"})

    for each in news:
        for div in each.find_all("div"):
            time= (div.find('span', attrs={'class': 'hh serif'}).text)
            tile=(" ".join([span.text for span in div.select("a > span")]))

            news1 = (f" {time} {'TEXAS RANGER'}, {title}")            
            textbox.insert(tk.END, news1)


    #DETROIT TIGERS
    site_detroit = requests.get('.....')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(site_detroit.content, 'html.parser')
    news = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "tcc-list-news"})

    for each in news:
        for div in each.find_all("div"):
            time= (div.find('span', attrs={'class': 'hh serif'}).text)
            title=(" ".join([span.text for span in div.select("a > span")]))

            news2 = (f" {time} {'DETROIT'}, {title}")       
            textbox.insert(tk.END, news2)


    #sorted
    from datetime import datetime

    allnews = news1, news2
    allnews.sort()


titoli()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: first put all in one list, next sort this list, and finally display elements from list in textbox

Comment: `allnews = news1, news2` creates tuple with two list, (use `pritn(allnews)` to see what you really have) and it can change which list will be first and which second in this tuple. It can't sort all elements as single list. You would have to add lists `news1 + news2` to create single list. And you have to do it before you insert items  to `textbox`.

Comment: frankly you should get error because `allnews = news1, news2` gives `tuple` and `tuple` doesn't have `sort()`.

Comment: I see other problem - `news1` has only last text about `TEXAS RANGER`, and `news2` has only last text about `DETROIT`. You should create `allnews = []` before loops, inside loops you should only append to this list `allnews.append(news1)`, etc. after loops you should sort list, and later you should insert news to `textarea`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it in wrong order. First you have to create empty list, next in loops you have to append news to this list (without displaying), after loop you have to sort list (with `reverse=True`), and later use loop to add values to `textbox`

Something like this

```
def titoli():

    # --- before loops ---
    
    allnews = []

    # --- loops ---
    
    #TEXAS RANGER
    site_texasrangers = requests.get('....')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(site_texasrangers.content, 'html.parser')
    news = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "tcc-list-news"})

    for each in news:
        for div in each.find_all("div"):
            time  = div.find('span', attrs={'class': 'hh serif'}).text
            title = " ".join([span.text for span in div.select("a > span")])

            news = f" {time} {'TEXAS RANGER'}, {title})"            

            allnews.append(news)  # <-- append to list without displaying

    #DETROIT TIGERS
    site_detroit = requests.get('.....')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(site_detroit.content, 'html.parser')
    news = soup.find_all('div', attrs={"class": "tcc-list-news"})

    for each in news:
        for div in each.find_all("div"):
            time  = div.find('span', attrs={'class': 'hh serif'}).text
            title = " ".join([span.text for span in div.select("a > span")])

            news = f" {time} {'DETROIT'}, {title})"            

            allnews.append(news)  # <-- append to list without displaying

    # --- after loops --- 

    allnews.sort(reverse=True)

    for news in allnews:
        textbox.insert(tk.END, news)
```

Comment: A thousand thanks. Everything is OK. A curiosity: in my scraping code I used headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla / 5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 39.0.2171.95 Safari / 537.36'
    }. You haven't used it and it works equally well. What's the difference between using headers and not using it? Thank you

Comment: some servers use this header to generate different HTML for different browsers on different devices (phone, notebook, desktop). Some servers use it to detect bots/scripts and blocks them. But many servers don't check it and it can be skiped. So usually I start without this header or add short `Mozilla/5.0` because I don't remeber full version. And if it doesn't work with server then I copy full header from my browser.